# Detecting Numbers in Image using pytesseract

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I have this image:

[image: Gauge]

I would like to detect the numbers within the image, mainly 2261 using Tesseract (pytesseract). I have tried various processing techniques with opencv, and I haven't been able to get tesseract to detect anything.

This is my current code:

```py
def get_grayscale(image):
    return cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

img1 = cv2.imread('runs/detect/exp/crops/Gauge/image0.jpg')

scale_percent = 220 # percent of original size
width = int(img1.shape[1] * scale_percent / 100)
height = int(img1.shape[0] * scale_percent / 100)
dim = (width, height)

resized = cv2.resize(img1, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
 
resized = get_grayscale(resized)

thr = cv2.threshold(src=resized, thresh=0, maxval=255, type=cv2.THRESH_OTSU + cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]

txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(thr, config='digits')
print(txt)

cv2.imshow("",thr)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

This produces the following image:

[image: Result]

As stated earlier, tesseract is unable to detect anything, and I'm unsure why, as the numbers are quite visible in this image. Am I missing something, or are there certain config options I need to include?

Comment: You might try the Google Vision api https://cloud.google.com/vision/

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney I'll have a look into, but ideally I would like to process it locally.

Comment: If you have many of these images, you can train tesseract. Otherwise you may be SOL

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney I have a fair few images. What are the steps I would need to take to train tesseract?

Comment: Here's a current example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KE4xEzFGSU8&ab_channel=GabrielGarcia. However, you probably need to have a lot of labeled images to train the model.